# How to Draw a Tornado Diagram by D3.JS?

Tags: d3.js

Any one who could help or grant an example of drawing a tornado diagram as follows by D3.JS?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this perfect example:

https://vida.io/documents/4fH9AwhtELEcrWnS6